# Prove that $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n^{\underline{k}}$

Tags: factorial

I'm having some trouble proving the relation $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n^{\underline{k}}$$

Do you have to get into using gamma functions in order to prove this rigorously? Also, wikipedia seems to indicate this is an exact relation, while the thermodynamics books I'm learning out of has a question where it says the two are  equal in the limit that $k \ll n$. And finally, why is the $k$ underlined? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $\large\underline{k}\ $ ?.

Comment: Without any familiarity with thermodynamics, I can only surmise that the underline indeed has meaning as a notation (since clearly $n^k\neq\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$). Do you know what it stands for, or if not, can you specify which Wiki entry you've been looking at?

Comment: The definition can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation you are referring to is called the falling factorial. For integer $k$ it is defined as $n^{\underline{k}} = n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)$. It follows immediately that this equals $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ (both are the product of integers from $n-k+1$ to $n$.

Comment: Ahh ok, I knew the falling factorial existed but I had no idea of that notation. Thanks =)